# SQL query to return records based on number of columns populated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of Items. The item id is stored in the `ITEM` column. All of the items have different variants, named `"80"`, `"85"`, `"90"`, `"95"`, `"100"`, `"105"`, `"110"`, `"115"` (also existing columns). If an item has a special kind of variant, the column (named by the variant type) is filled with a number.

I'd like to select only those items, which have at least 4 variants (4 variant columns are filled with number).

```
ITEM    80    85    90    95    100    105    110    115
 A      1                        1                    3    <-- 3 variants
 B      2                        1                    3    <-- 3 variants
 C                        1                           3    <-- 2 variants
 D            1                                       3    <-- 2 variants
 E      1                 1                     1     1    <-- 4 variants
```

In this example, **Item E** would be the only one selected as it has 4 variants.

```
create table itemtest (
    item varchar2(30 char),
    "80" integer,
    "85" integer,
    "90" integer,
    "95" integer,
    "100" integer,
    "105" integer,
    "110" integer,
    "115" integer
);

insert into itemtest values ('A', 1, null, null, null, 1, null, null, 3);

insert into itemtest values ('B', 2, null, null, null, 1, null, null, 3);

insert into itemtest values ('C', null, null, null, 1, null, null, null, 3);

insert into itemtest values ('D', null, 1, null, null, null, null, null, 3);

insert into itemtest values ('E', 1, null, null, 1, null, null, 1, 1);

commit;
```

Comment: I'm not sure when the question is going to be reopened, but you can use the NVL2 function to do what you want.  On a NULL value, return 0, otherwise return 1.  Do this for every column and add the result, and select where the Result = 4.

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself from typing tedious `CASE` expressions. Use Oracle's underrated [`NVL2()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm) function for this!

```
select itemtest.*
from itemtest
where NVL2("80" , 1, 0) + NVL2("85" , 1, 0) + 
      NVL2("90" , 1, 0) + NVL2("95" , 1, 0) + 
      NVL2("100", 1, 0) + NVL2("105", 1, 0) + 
      NVL2("110", 1, 0) + NVL2("115", 1, 0) >= 4;
```

From the docs:

> ```
> NVL2(expr1, expr2, expr3)
> ```
>
> NVL2 lets you determine the value returned by a query based on whether a specified expression is null or not null. If expr1 is not null, then NVL2 returns expr2. If expr1 is null, then NVL2 returns expr3.

#### Bonus. Impress (or annoy) your coworkers with the beautiful UNPIVOT clause

I don't know why I hadn't thought of it earlier. In fact, you're really unpivoting your columns in order to count them. Here's how:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*)
FROM itemtest
UNPIVOT (
  variants FOR code IN ("80", "85", "90", "95", "100", "105", "110", "115")
)
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
ORDER BY item
```

This will yield

```
ITEM  COUNT(*)
--------------
E            4
```

**How it works?**

Here's a simple `UNPIVOT` statement without grouping and aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM itemtest
UNPIVOT (
  variants FOR code IN ("80", "85", "90", "95", "100", "105", "110", "115")
)
```

Which yields...

```
ITEM  CODE  VARIANTS
--------------------
A     80    1       
A     100   1       
A     115   3       
B     80    2       
B     100   1       
B     115   3       
C     95    1       
C     115   3       
D     85    1       
D     115   3       
E     80    1       
E     95    1       
E     110   1       
E     115   1
```

The rest (`GROUP BY` and `HAVING`) is just ordinary SQL.

Comment: I take your point about `CASE` and tedious verbosity, but I do like their self-documenting nature. It's very obvious what they're doing whereas `NVL2` needs a bit of a commentary along with it.

Comment: It's easy to remember what `NVL2` is. `NVL` translates to "null value", and `NVL2` is just a silly name when some Oracle engineer couldn't think of a smarter name. Like `VARCHAR2` ;-)

Comment: Yes, "The Return of NVL" - but remembering which way round `expr2`, and `expr3` go needs some googletastic docs.

Comment: @NickPierpoint: `NVL(expr, ifNull)`... `NVL2(expr, ifNull, ifNotNull)`. Seems logical to me.

Comment: @NickPierpoint: OK, I agree. `UNPIVOT` is probably better suited for the task at hand, than `NVL2` :-)

Comment: Now you're just not playing fair. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just count them up and select when greater or equal to 4

```
select *
from itemtest 
where
   CASE WHEN "80" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "85" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "90" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "95" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "100" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "105" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "110" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN "115" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return rows based on the number of variants, you can use a CASE statement to check how many columns are populated:

```
select
    i.item
from
    (
    select
        item,
            case when "80"  is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "85"  is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "90"  is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "95"  is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "100" is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "105" is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "110" is not null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when "115" is not null then 1 else 0 end num_variants
    from
        itemtest
    ) i
where
    num_variants >= 4;
```

You're probably stuck with the design, but it would have been much easier if the possible variants were held in a separate ITEM_VARIANT table:

```
 ITEM  VARIANT_CODE  VARIANT_VALUE
 ----  ------------  -------------
  A        80            1
  A       100            1
  A       115            3
  B        80            2
  ...
  ...
  ...
  E       115            1
```

Then you have a nice straightforward query - something like the following for example:

```
select
    item
from
    (
    select
        item,
        count(*) num_variants
    from
        item_variant
    group by
        item
    )
where
    num_variants >= 4;
```